# curl request to google places api returns "bool(false)"

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I've tried using the Javascript version of google places API, but now I'd like to move the code to server side with an API key. I've tried using all possible permutations and combinations of the curl request, but couldn't find a solution to it.

```
$url = urlencode('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=' . $input . '&types=establishment&location=13.052415, 80.250824&radius=500&sensor=true&key=KEY');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

NOTE: I've used my app's KEY in the "key" params.

Response I get => bool(false)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use urlencode for the complete URL, use it only for the values of the parameters